# Prevent showing tooltip on popover

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, tooltip, popover

I need < a > tag which shoud display tooltip on cursor moving and should drop popover on clicking. But tooltip is also shown when I move cursor above popover. Check it: https://jsfiddle.net/ivictbor/re15cuby/2/ .

Html:

```
 <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="sometext"> 
    <a id="my_uniq_id" href="javascript:void(0);" >          
        link</a>
   </span>
```

JS:

```
$( "#my_uniq_id" ).on( "click", function drop_popover() {
 id = 'my_uniq_id'
 var el = $("#"+id);
 $( "body" ).append(
        '<div id="' +id+'_hldr'+'" style="display: none;">'+
          'popover holder code'+
        '</div>'
 );
 el.popover({ 
        placement : 'bottom',
        html : true,
        trigger: 'manual',
        title: ': <a href="#" style="float:right;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" '+
        'onclick="$(\'#'+id+'\').popover(\'hide\');"></span></a>',
        content: function() {
          return $('#'+id+'_hldr').html();
        },
    }).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    el.popover('show');
})

$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({html: true})
})
```

Comment: "on cursor moving"??

Comment: see https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16671399/tooltip_on_popup.gif

Comment: "on cursor moving" == "on hover" ?

Comment: Sounds like you want `container: 'body'` in your popover options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to add 'container: 'body'' in popover options:

```
el.popover({ 
    placement : 'bottom',
    container: 'body',
    html : true,
```

Thanks to cvrebert

Comment: To explain a bit more: By default, the popover's DOM was getting appended as a sibling of its `<a id="my_uniq_id">` trigger element, which means it's also a child of your `<span data-toggle="tooltip" ...>`. Hence, the popover was within the tooltip's trigger! On the other hand, `container: 'body'` makes the popover get appended to the `<body>` instead. The trade-off is that now the popover will no longer "stick" to its trigger if you scroll the page.

Answer (score 0):

That should do the trick:

```
 $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({html: true}).on('click', function(){
            $(this).tooltip('hide');
        });
```